# How can I use Navigate in Rickett version 6?

Tags: react-navigation, history

I want to check if the token exists. If there is no token, I redirect the user to the login page
Because I use the hook, the useNavigate command gives an error, as well as the command history.push(
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCxM9.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOcHo.png)

action.props.history.push('/') dont work